# Google Guava Iterate All Files Starting From a Begin Directory

Tags: java, file, guava

I use Google Guava at my code. Starting from a directory I want to get all the files by one by (if current file is some special file I will do some process inside it) and at the end I will copy them into another directory(except for some directories.)

I know that there is a copy method at Guava however how can I get all the files under a directory (if there are some directories under starting directory I should get files under it too and if there is any directory under some of that directories I should get them too)

**PS 1:** If there is any suggestion for copying files you are welcome.

**PS 2:** I think this conversation is related with my question: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=578

**PS 3:** I use Java 6 at my project.

Comment: What about simply using recursion?

Comment: with `isFile()` `isDirectory()`

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I think Guava should have such kind of methods.

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW they are just checking either it is a file or not but main problem is iterating beginning from a start directory.

Comment: IIRC, they removed some directory nagivation methods in Guava because they were buggy on *nix (i.e. with links)

Answer (score 15):

Since Guava 15 you can use [`Files.fileTreeTraverser()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#fileTreeTraverser%28%29).

The usage is very simple:

```
File rootDir = ...; //this is your root directory
for (File f : Files.fileTreeTraverser().preOrderTraversal(rootDir)) {
    // do whatever you need with the file/directory

    // if you need the relative path, with respect to rootDir
    Path relativePath = rootDir.toPath().getParent().relativize(f.toPath());
}
```

As you can read from [`TreeTraverser`'s javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeTraverser.html), you can choose between three different iteration orders.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to Java 7, use `walkFileTree` in `Files`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately I should use Java 6 for my project.

Answer (score 0):

- Copy file by Guava

  Some [Files.copy](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#copy%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) overloading methods are found in Guava 14.0, for single file copy.
- Walk files

  As some suggested, you could use recursive call. (`DirectoryScanner` you mentioned is good)

Comment: I think that DirectoryScanner recursive walk is not implemented yet at Guava?

Comment: No, the class is not part of Guava.